# Putting .sty file into ~/texmf-dist/tex/latex But still getting Error

Tags: packages, texlive, texmaker

I installed texLive 2013 on a mac. And I am using texmaker to typeset my documents. I have my threads regarding where to locate `.sty` files in mac. And I located my `stackengine.sty` in the following path

`\usr\local\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\tex\latex`

This is where all the packages are. So I believe putting my `stackengine.sty` in there will make sense, which is what I did.

I then tried to compile my tex file. But it failed miserably with the following error message in the log:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def
File: latin9.def 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
))
! LaTeX Error: File `stackengine.sty' not found.
```

I already placed the `stackengine.sty` in that path already. I even placed the entire `stackengine` there as well. Still, the same error kept coming up. What have I done wrong here ?

Comment: those directories are pre-indexed so you will need to run texhash or similar but basically you should never copy files by hand into the tree under texmf-dist that is under the control of the package manager so issuing `tlmgr install stackengine` should fetch the file install it and update the index automatically

Comment: I have never used the terminal before. I am not entirely sure where should I execute the `tlmgr install stackengine` command ?

Comment: Did you install MacTeX? If so, I'm pretty sure you should have a GUI application which is a front-end for `tlmgr`. If you want to use the command line, you need to run the Terminal application. This may be in `/Applications/Utilities/` but I'm not sure. (It used to live there but I am not up to date.) By the way, your question says `~/texmf-dist/...` but that would be `/Users/yourusername/texmf-dist/...` as the `~` is shorthand for your home directory.

Comment: @asd probably you can execute it from anywhere, but I would imagine that texmaker has a menu option in its GUI (but I don't have texmaker or a mac so I leave others to fill in those details:-)

Comment: Perhaps this page on [the mactex wiki](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/TeX_Live_Manager) helps? It seems to be a bit outdated (referring to TeXLive 2008 all the time), but the process described is fairly similar to the current workflow on linux, so I'd think it doesn't differ too much.

Comment: Open Tex Live Utility click on the `Packages` tab and type `stackengine` into the search field on the top right. once you see the package, verify that it's status is `Not installed`. Right click on it and choose `Install Selected Packages`. It should say `successful instal` once it's done. check this screenshot:

http://i.imgur.com/znbmidZ.png